# C++ IRC Socket Doesn't Connect. Error 10014

Tags: c++, sockets, irc

I'm trying to create a little IRC Library in C++. 
When using RAW sockets, it doesn't seem to connect.

It's nowhere near complete - hence only two functions.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
using namespace std;

class Bot
{
    SOCKET sock;
public:
    void Init();
    void Connect(const char* servername, int port, const char* nick);
};

void Bot::Init()
{
    WSADATA WSAData;
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WSAData) != 0)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Failed WSAStartup" << endl;
    }
    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Invalid Socket\n";
    }
}

void Bot::Connect(const char* servername, int port, const char* nick)
{
    hostent* host;
    host = gethostbyname(servername);
    sockaddr_in sockAddr;
    sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    sockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = ((in_addr *)(host->h_addr))->s_addr;
    while(connect(sock, (sockaddr *) &sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Can't connect to Socket.\n"; //This is the problem
        Sleep(10000.0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Bot bot;
    bot.Init();
    bot.Connect("wolfe.freenode.net", 6777, "nick");
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated - I'm utterly stuck.
The connection problem is here:

```
while(connect(sock, (sockaddr *) &sockAddr, sizeof(&sockAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
```

so i'm going to assume the problem is in

```
void Bot::Connect(const char* servername, int port, const char* nick)
```

**Edit:**
If I change

```
SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

to

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

i now get Error code 10014 (It now doesn't shadow the member variable)

Comment: What is returned by errno/GetLastError/whatever after the failed connect?

Comment: Was the name resolution successful?  Did it return a null pointer?  You cannot ignore possible errors from system calls.  Have you used a debugger?

Comment: If you did use a debugger, what did you find out?

Comment: GetLastError returns 10038

Comment: no you are shadowing the member variable i think. Leave it as `sock` but remove `SOCKET`?

Comment: you are basically making a socket local to the Init function, and thus never initialize the member variable `sock` i think

Comment: Now i get 10014 :) (But, yes, you were right on that bit, thanks)

Comment: yes, i believe my comments still stand - you basically never initialize `Bot::sock`

Comment: hm ok let me try to look a little more, but i've never worked with sockets so i doubt i'll be of much help. 10014 says the memory structure isn't the proper length, so let's see what isn't being allocated correctly

Comment: @imsoconfused - oh yeah - I looked at this for ages but didn't spot the hiding of the original declaration, +1.

Comment: There again, if I made such a mistake, (and I do, often), I find it quickly and fix it because I know how to use a debugger which, it seems, is becoming a lost art.

Comment: @MartinJames you're telling me - my job recently moved to Cloud development, and the lack of good cloud debugging tools (before VS2013 + Azure SDK) and peoples' attitude to "Just Trace It(TM)" had(has - we still don't support VS2013) me about to pull out my hair!